# Using two style.css for the same react app

Tags: css, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to use two snippets as components from bootsnipp, and each snippet has its own css. i tried to put them both in the style.css, but it ended up damaging one component for the other to look fine. 
I'm thinking about how to use both these styles.css, since in the index.js i can only import style.css.

can i use router to use multiple pages, and import style.css in the second page? but wouldn't that mean i'll have to use the second page as app.js, which is called only once in react? this is kind of confusing me.

EDIT: can I put the css of one component in another css file, and then import it INSIDE that component instead of index.js?
it doesn't bother me by the way whether i put that component inside index.js or not; in fact, I'm not going to use it there.

Comment: Could you rename one of the files and import them where needed?

Or you can inspect the broken page to see which rules are being overwritten and write more specific CSS rules for these elements.

Comment: I did, and i imported one in the component i need, but it stil overwrote the other one :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say you need to deal with the global namespace issue. You could create two components with its own css file.

Then add a unique `className` to stop collisions.

The benefit here is that you could also enable code spitting, so you would only load html/css/js when you need it (see `React.lazy`).

—-

By trying to load two styles in different times or manners you will still have the same issue of conflicting styles.

Comment: Within your template, `div className=“CUSTOM_CLASSNAME”>{this.props.children}</div>`

Comment: i'm sorry, i don't fully understand. can you explain more?

Comment: Can you post your 2 code snippets, I will update my answer.

Comment: I've actually managed to fix it. Just fiddled with one of the css' properties so that it doesn't overwrite the other. thank you! : )